# obtaining and plotting wave-vectors from fft

Tags: matlab, fft

I have a data set that describes the instantaneous velocity of a medium ranging from `x=0` to `x=0.4` (with 32 nodes the spatial increment is then 0.0125).

I would like to apply an FFT to this, this I do in the following piece of code where `data` contains the velocities:

```
data = [-0.0005
   -0.0004
   -0.0003
   -0.0002
   -0.0001
   -0.0000
    0.0001
    0.0001
    0.0001
    0.0002
    0.0002
    0.0002
    0.0002
    0.0002
    0.0002
    0.0002
    0.0002
    0.0002
    0.0003
    0.0004
    0.0005
    0.0006
    0.0007
    0.0009
    0.0010
    0.0011
    0.0011
    0.0012
    0.0011
    0.0011
    0.0011
    0.0010 ];


N = 100;
X=abs(fft(data,N));
X = fftshift(X);
F = [-N/2:N/2-1]/N;

figure(1)
plot(F,X)
```

However, I am not sure about what values of the wavevector the `x`-axis represents in the plot. In principle I want the wave vectors, but is there a way to get that from the FFT?

Comment: what is the wavevector? The FFT's x-axis is the frequency while y-axis is the relative abundance of that frequency in the signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `F`, running from -0.5 (inclusive) to +0.5 (exclusive), represents frequency relative to the underlying sample rate (the Nyquist frequency). Since your original signal `X` is sampled at uniform spacing of 0.0125 meters per sample, or a sample frequency of 80 samples per meter, `F / 0.0125` represents your real-world spatial frequency in units of cycles per meter. Makes sense?

Comment: Then the maximum of `X` is 40. When you say it is in units of cycles per length, does that mean that basically a given `X` is 1/(length of medium)?

Comment: What I mean is, is there a factor of 2*pi included as well when you say it is in units of cycles per meter?

Comment: Ah, not quite. Here’s the complete breakdown: your `F` has units of “normalized” cycles per meter (normalization factor is sample rate, 80 samples per meter). `F / 0.0125` has units of “true” cycles per meter. `F / 0.125 * 2 * pi` has units of radians per meter, since 2π radians is 1 cycle. Each element of any of these frequency vectors tells you the frequency matching the magnitude in `X`.

Comment: Thanks. So the largest real-world spatial frequency for my system is 40 per-meter. Does this imply that the smallest perturbation I can resolve is 1/0.025 per-meter?

Comment: That is the standard definition of “resolution”—two sinusoids with frequencies separated by ≳ a resolution bin are separable. (It doesn’t say anything about the resolvability of the frequency of a single sinusoid though: if you know your signal contains a single sinusoid, its frequency can be estimated far better than a resolution cell in low-noise cases.) In your case, since you have 32 spatial samples separated by 0.0125 meters, the resolution cell is `1 / 32 / 0.0125 = 2.5` cycles per meter. (Your `N = 100` just oversamples the FFT, it doesn’t add any resolution to the underlying signal.)